# How can I compile a C function into a numpy ufunc and load it dynamically?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, ctypes

I have some Python code that automatically generates a C function. This function takes some doubles as input and returns a double, calling various functions from the C standard library along the way.

One of the things I would like to do with this is compile it into a numpy ufunc and load it into the running Python process. I just want the function to run element-wise on its input numpy arrays, like numpy's `minimum` for example, at reasonable speed.

I was surprised that I couldn't find clear instructions or examples how to do this. Numpy has clear instructions on writing extensions, but it's not clear how I could load these into the current Python process. With ctypes I can compile my function and load it, no problem, but it's not clear how to make it a ufunc rather than a normal Python function. Cython can also do this, and if I use `pyximport` it will even build the shared library for me, which is ideal because then I can distribute it without worrying about how to build the C code on another system. But again it's not clear how to make a ufunc rather than a normal function.

TL;DR: how can I take a simple C function, compile it into a ufunc, and load it dynamically? The more foolproof and less boilerplate the better.

Comment: Have you found ["Writing your own ufunc"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html)? You can probably take the boilerplate [from the example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html#example-numpy-ufunc-for-one-dtype) and call your existing native C function from inside.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'd seen that but saw ~10 screensful of boilerplate code and baulked. Somewhere in that page will I learn how to import the ufunc without restarting Python?

Comment: Read the second link in my updated comment. There's an example, then "*After the above has been installed, it can be imported and used as follows.*". You will always have to compile C code in order to be able to import it. And since things are usually imported once I'm unsure about "without restarting python" but that step comes later.

Comment: Also, you probably only have to change the names and the three lines between "_BEGIN/END main ufunc_" in the logit example.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it says: "...the module can be build via calling python setup.py build at the command prompt, or installed to site-packages via python setup.py install." Does that mean I have to spawn a second Python process to run `setup.py`, or can I do it from within the Python process that's already running? (The one that just generated the C code, and into which I wish to import the ufunc.) As for only having to change three lines, well fine, but I don't like to use boilerplate code without understanding it, and there is a *lot* there that needs to be unpicked.

Comment: (If the boilerplate is necessary then fine, I will learn all that stuff, but was hoping ctypes or cython would provide an out-of-the-box automatic solution without it. I actually had a vague memory of that existing, but maybe I didn't recall correctly, as I can't seem to find it.)

Comment: My understanding is that there's a lot of low-level magic going on in order to make ufuncs work (the complete [ufunc machinery](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) has to be extended to a naive C function). Hence all the boilerplate. Plus you expect to end up with a reasonable docstring on the python side, which again amounts to some boilerplate. Anyway, my understanding is that installing packages changes the environment, so you need to restart python anyway. If we remove ufuncs from the picture, how about pip installing a module on the fly?

Comment: @AndrasDeak ctypes and cython can both import C shared libraries without any need for installing anything, so it's surely possible.

Comment: So I'd expect the "without restarting python" part to be independent of numpy being used. If you can figure out if/how it's possible to run setup.py without having to restart, you'll have your answer. But why are you against restarting?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't want to restart because the C function is autogenerated based on user input. I want to seamlessly compile it, load it, and run it 'behind the scenes', without the user having to worry about .so files and such.

Comment: The lack of available resources on the subject might mean that you could also try asking about the same thing on the numpy issue tracker. If this is a feature which isn't documented (well enough?) it could be welcome.

Comment: If you use `cython` you can create a `.so` file that can be imported anytime.  A full `ufunc` interface may be more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

One idea could be to use numba for [creating ufuncs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) and [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for compiling the c-code.

For example if we want to double the value of every element in a numpy-array, i.e. having  the following C-function as a string:

```
double f(double a){
    return 2.0*a;
}
```

a possible solution is the following prototype:

```
import numba as nb
import cffi

def create_ufunc(code):
    # 1. step: compile the C-code and load the resulting extension
    ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()
    ffibuilder.cdef("double f(double a);", override=True)
    built_module=ffibuilder.verify(source=code)
    fun = built_module.f

    # 2. step: create an ufunc out of the compiled C-function
    @nb.vectorize([nb.float64(nb.float64)])
    def f(x):
      return fun(x)
    return f
```

And now:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(6).astype(np.float64)
my_f1=create_ufunc("double f(double a){return 2.0*a;}")
my_f1(a)
# array([  0.,   2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.])
```

or if we want to multiply with `10.0`:

```
my_f2=create_ufunc("double f(double a){return 10.0*a;}")
# array([  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.])
```

Obviosly, while showing what is possible, this prototype needs some polishing. For example albeit compact, [`verify`](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffi-verify-in-line-api-mode) is deprecated and calling `create_ufunc` twice with the same code will lead to a warning.

Another issue: the version above does not compile in the nopython-mode, despite the fact that cffi-functions [are supported  by numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#cffi). Not sure what is going wrong here? See further below for a workaround: a more complicated version which builds in nopython mode.

However, this is probably still a good starting point.

---

It seems to be possible to compile numba in nopython-mode, if we use [out-of-line](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffibuilder-compile-etc-compiling-out-of-line-modules) (`compile`) instead of [in-line](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffi-verify-in-line-api-mode) (`verify`) API-mode:

```
import numba as nb
import cffi
import zlib
import importlib
import numba.cffi_support as nbcffi

def create_ufunc(code):
    # 1. step: compile the C-code and load the resulting extension
    # create a different so/dll for different codes
    # and load it
    module_name="myufunc"+str(zlib.adler32(code.encode('ascii')))
    ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()
    ffibuilder.cdef("double f(double a);", override=True)
    ffibuilder.set_source(module_name=module_name,source=code)
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
    loaded = importlib.import_module(module_name)


    # 2. step: create an ufunc out of the compiled C-function
    # out-of-line modules must be registered in numba:      
    nbcffi.register_module(loaded)
    fun = loaded.lib.f

    @nb.vectorize([nb.float64(nb.float64)], nopython=True)
    def f(x):
      return fun(x)
    return f
```

Important details:

- There is a new extension (so/pyd-file) for every `code`. We distinguish between them via hash-value of the passed `code`.
- over the time there will be quite some `myufuncXXXX.so`-files around, one could think about implementing an infrastructure similar to one used by `cffi.verify`.
- `ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)` is just for debugging purposes, probably `verbose=False` makes more sense in release.

Comment: This numba based approach is very nice! It seems to work seamlessly with ctypes also, using nopython mode. (This saves one dependency at the cost of the build process not being automatic.)