# Undefined behavior when using Cython and external multithreaded C library

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cython

I am new to Cython (as well as Python), and I am trying to understand where I am doing wrong when I try to expose the C-API of an external multithreaded library to Python. To illustrate my problem, I will go over a hypothetical MWE.

Let's assume that I have the following directory structure

```
.
├── app.py
├── c_mylib.pxd
├── cxx
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── mylib.h
│   └── src
│       └── reduce_cb.cpp
├── mylib.pyx
└── setup.py
```

Here, `cxx` contains the external multithreaded library as follows (header and implementation files are concatenated):

```cpp
/* cxx/include/mylib.h */
#ifndef MYLIB_H_
#define MYLIB_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef double (*func_t)(const double *, const double *, void *);
double reduce_cb(const double *, const double *, func_t, void *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif

/* cxx/src/reduce_cb.cpp */
#include <iterator>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "mylib.h"

extern "C" {
double reduce_cb(const double *xb, const double *xe, func_t func, void *data) {
  const auto d = std::distance(xb, xe);
  const auto W = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  const auto split = d / W;
  const auto remain = d % W;
  std::vector<std::thread> workers(W);
  double res{0};
  std::mutex lock;
  const double *xb_w{xb};
  const double *xe_w;
  for (unsigned int widx = 0; widx < W; widx++) {
    xe_w = widx < remain ? xb_w + split + 1 : xb_w + split;
    workers[widx] = std::thread(
        [&lock, &res, func, data](const double *xb, const double *xe) {
          const double partial = func(xb, xe, data);
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
          res += partial;
        },
        xb_w, xe_w);
    xb_w = xe_w;
  }
  for (auto &worker : workers)
    worker.join();
  return res;
}
}
```

with the accompanying `cxx/CMakeLists.txt` file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(dummy LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(mylib
  include/mylib.h
  src/reduce_cb.cpp
)
target_compile_features(mylib
  PRIVATE
    cxx_std_11
)
target_include_directories(mylib
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
set_target_properties(mylib
  PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/mylib.h
)
install(TARGETS mylib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include
)
```

The corresponding Cython files are as follows (this time definition and implementation files are concatenated):

```py
# c_mylib.pxd
cdef extern from "include/mylib.h":
  ctypedef double (*func_t)(const double *, const double *, void *)
  double reduce_cb(const double *, const double *, func_t, void *)

# mylib.pyx
# cython: language_level = 3
cimport c_mylib

cdef double func(const double *xb, const double *xe, void *data):
  cdef int d = (xe - xb)
  func = <object>data
  return func(<double[:d]>xb)

def reduce_cb(double [::1] arr not None, f):
  cdef int d = arr.shape[0]
  data = <void*>f
  return c_mylib.reduce_cb(&arr[0], &arr[0] + d, func, data)

# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  ext_modules=cythonize([
    Extension("mylib", ["mylib.pyx"], libraries=["mylib"])
  ])
)
```

Building the C++ library, and building the Cython extension module and linking it against the C++ library following the instructions, I get undefined behavior when I try to run

```py
import mylib
from numpy import array


def cb(x):
  partial = 0
  for idx in range(x.shape[0]):
    partial += x[idx]
  return partial


arr = array([val + 1 for val in range(100)], "d")
print("sum(arr): ", mylib.reduce_cb(arr, cb))
```

By undefined behavior, I mean that I get either of

1. `SIGSEGV` (Address boundary error),
2. "Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked" with `SIGABRT`, or,
3. (rarely) the correct result.

I have checked the documentation of Cython thoroughly (I guess), and I have searched both SO and Google for this problem, but I could not find a proper solution to this problem.

Basically, I would like to have a C library, which is *unaware* of Python and which uses callback functions from multiple threads, that is integrated inside Python. Is this at all possible? I tried `nogil` signatures and `with gil:` blocks as discussed in Cython's [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil), but I got compilation errors. Moreover, `gc` related functionality in Cython seems to be valid only for [extension types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#controlling-deallocation-and-garbage-collection-in-cpython), which does not apply to my case.

I am stuck and I would appreciate any hint/help.

Comment: Seems like the `with gil` / `with nogil` stuff is going to be critical. It's unsurprising to me that you have random-ish crashes without it. I think you need to work out the compilation errors you got there as the next step.

Comment: Thank you @GilHamilton. I will try to go thru them, and hopefully I can arrive somewhere meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when you use Python-objects/functionality without lock. Your critical section is not only the summation but also the call to function `func`, i.e.:

```
workers[widx] = std::thread(
    [&lock, &res, func, data](const double *xb, const double *xe) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
      const double partial = func(xb, xe, data); // must be guarded
      res += partial;
    },
    xb_w, xe_w);
```

which makes the parallelization senseless in the first place, doesn't it? Probably, from software-engineering  point of view, a better place for guard would be in the wrapper function `func` - but I have put it into `worker` because the consequences are seen much better this way.

Python uses reference counting for memory management - similar to `std::shared_ptr`. However it doesn't lock with fine granularity as shared_ptr, which locks only when changing the reference counter, but uses a more coarse lock - the global interpreter lock. That has the consequence, that when one changes the reference count of an python-object from open-MP-thread or other threads not registered in Python-interpreter the reference-counter is not protected/guarded and race conditions arise. What you are observing, are the possible results of such race conditions.

The GIL makes your endeavor more or less impossible: you need to lock every call to possible python but than you serialize the calls to this functionality!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In fact, you are right --- applying that one line change results in a proper, albeit serialized, run in Python. And yes, it does make the parallelization senseless. I would not think that the call to `func` is indeed a critical section, especially if `void *data` does not have any side effects. If I also enforce that the `data` is immutable (by making it `const void*` to model stateless function objects, for instance), then I can simply switch to using `std::atomic` and get rid of `std::mutex` altogether, I was assuming. In the end, `func` is operating on ...

Comment: ... different memory locations. But I assume that you already know this, and you are not interested in what happens in low-level languages such as C and C++, but rather trying to explain the problem with Python, where everything including the functions are objects. As far as I can see, serializing the call to `func` results in proper allocation/deallocation of `func = <object>data` inside Python, right? If yes, then I have understood it properly, and I thank you. One last question. You say the GIL makes this endeavor _more or less_ impossible. Do you see a possible (and easy) workaround?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin global state of Python interpreter (e.g. garbage collector) is touched when pure python code is executed and this should not be done without gil. Thus it will not work when arbitrary (probably any) python-function is wrapped and passed to worker. You could write some nogil-Cython functions and the user would then use one of them (this will also be much faster then python-versions).

Comment: It isn't necessarily a complete loss - if your function uses numpy functions (which tend to release the GIL) then it will be partly parallelised. Similarly (as ead suggests) you could write some Cython functions and release the GIL yourself.

Comment: @ArdaAytekin if you need more flexibility you could look into jit-compiled functions, here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52958324/5769463, but there are probably better fitting examples around.

Comment: Thank you, both @DavidW and @ead, for your comments. I have tried making the signature of `func` above `nogil`, but then the compiler complains about manipulating Python objects. Then, I protect the last two lines of `func` within `with gil:` block, which results in a deadlock (the application does not crash, but does not continue either). This is because, I assume, I give the object to a non-Python thread spawned inside the library, which is another violation (as I do not `Py_Initialize` anywhere). Basically, I _could_ write pure Cython function to implement `cb`, easily, but then ...

Comment: ... I seem to lose the flexibility to have (sort of) dynamic dispatch of `cb` (i.e., the user _should_ be allowed to pass any dynamic object to decide on the logic, _without_ being constrained to a bunch of Cython-compiled functions). Apparently, I am just trying to force something that cannot be doable in its current form. I will check the JIT-compiled functions, too.